# How to select element based on ID and gt all the InnerHtml using HTML Agilitypack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, webforms, html-agility-pack

I need to pull part of html from external url to another page using agility-pack. I am not sure if i can select a node/element based on id or classname using agility pack. So far i manage to pull complete page but i want to target on node/element with specific id and all its contents.

```
protected void WebScrapper()
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        var url = @"https://www.itftennis.com/en/tournament/w15-valencia/esp/2022/w-itf-esp-35a-2022/acceptance-list/"; 

        var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
        doc = webGet.Load(url);
        var baseUrl = new Uri(url);
        //doc.LoadHtml(doc);
        Response.Write(doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml);
        //Response.Write(doc.DocumentNode.Id("acceptance-list-container"));

        //var innerContent = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/div").FirstOrDefault().InnerHtml;

    }
```

When i use `Response.Write(doc.DocumentNode.Id("acceptance-list-container"))` it generates error.

When i use below code it generates error `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/div[@id='acceptance-list-container']").FirstOrDefault().InnerHtml;
```

so far nothing works if you fix one issue other issue shows up.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get indicates that the `SelectNodes()` call didn't find any nodes and returned `null`. In cases like this, it is useful to inspect the actual HTML by using `doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml`.

Your code sample is somewhat messy and you are probably trying to do too many things at once (what is `Response.Write()` for example?). You should try to focus on one thing at a time if possible.

Here is a simple unit test that can get you started:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Xunit;
using Xunit.Abstractions;

namespace Scraping.Tests
{
    public class ScrapingTests
    {
        private readonly ITestOutputHelper _outputHelper;

        public ScrapingTests(ITestOutputHelper outputHelper)
        {
            _outputHelper = outputHelper;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
            const string url = @"https://www.itftennis.com/en/tournament/w15-valencia/esp/2022/w-itf-esp-35a-2022/acceptance-list/"; 

            var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = webGet.Load(url);

            string html = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
            
            _outputHelper.WriteLine(html); // use this if you just want to print something

            Assert.Contains("acceptance-list-container", html); // use this if you want to automate an assertion
        }
    }
}
```

When I tried that the first time, I got some HTML with an `iframe`. I visited the page in a browser and I was presented with a google captcha. After completing the captcha, I was able to view the page in the browser, but the HTML in the unit test was still different from the one I got in the browser.

Interestingly enough, the HTML in the unit test contains the following:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

It is obvious that this website has some security measures in place in order to block web scrapers. If you manage to overcome this obstacle and get the actual page's HTML in your program, parsing it and getting the parts that you need will be straightforward.

Comment: Hi, Yes i tried too many thing and lost the track, i use `Response.Write`  for testing in actual i want to put all the data inside div.. Also i noticed i get error is because ITF website using React to load on page load using API calls possibly, When i make call data is not there so i was not also sure to to add delay so that full will make call after all data is loaded on the page..

Comment: Adding a delay won't help you because HAP does not execute any javascript code. If the DOM you want to scrape is generated by javascript (e.g. React), then you will need to use another tool. See if [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/) with a javascript engine can do that. If not you might need to use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) or something similar.